# EJB - Container Managed Transaction Logging (TOMEE)

Tags: java, jpa, ejb, java-ee-7, openjpa

I am using TOMEE(apache-tomee-7.1.1-webprofile) for development purpose to deploy J2EE application and
I want to know how the transaction is working in TOMEE with my application.

Environment

- EJB 3.x
- OPENJPA 2.x
- Oracle

**Question**

1. How to enable logging for Transaction related stuffs to know in TOMEE logs.
2. My business methods are included @TransactionAttribute annotations (NotSupported, RequiresNew) so I want to know what's happening in those method Transaction in details.

   Is there any way to know the Transaction in details ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have tomee but you can increase the logging in your app or in the tomcat server logs

you can increase the logging level in  tomcat server logs `<tomcat_install_dir>/conf/logging.properties`

add lines

```
log4j.category.Transaction=DEBUG
log4j.category.openjpa=INFO
```

see links for more info
http://tomee.apache.org/tomee-8.0/docs/tomee-logging.html
http://tomee.apache.org/tomee-7.1/examples/testing-transactions.html

Comment: Hi @PrasadU, Thanks for your answer, When I change the log4j.category.Transaction into debug or info then Tomee is not starting, Its says below error

`org.apache.xbean.propertyeditor.PropertyEditorException: Unable to resolve class Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ` and the jar file (xbean-reflect-4.14.jar) is available in the lib folder of Tomee.